# Why is the pronunciation the same for récupéreras and récupéras?

Tags: prononciation

I know French is well known for its illogical spelling with regards to pronunciation but I was puzzled at these two words being the same despite the conjugation being different **and** the addition of a syllable. But everywhere I checked the pronunciation appears to be the same.

https://conjugueur.reverso.net/conjugaison-francais-verbe-r%C3%A9cup%C3%A9rer.html

https://www.deepl.com/fr/translator#fr/en/r%C3%A9cup%C3%A9ras

https://www.deepl.com/fr/translator#fr/en/r%C3%A9cup%C3%A9reras

Is this really the case?

Also seems to be the same with other words that have a similar structure to this, like préféreras and préféras. I wonder what the reason for this extra syllable not affecting pronunciation.

Comment: I guess you don't have the ear to tell yet, but they don't sound the same, neither on DeepL nor on google translate. There's an audible stop in "récupèr**e**ras". Also, just because the reason is obscure doesn't mean it's "illogical" :)

Comment: @TeleportingGoat The chain of events that leads from "femme" as "fème" to "femme" as "fame" does have its logic but the end result from the point of view of the plain correspondence between spelling and sound _is_ illogical; that's most likely what user Hasen has in mind.

Answer (score 2):

The *e* in récupéreras is *e muet,* like the second *e* in *appeler* or the final *e* in *appelle.* If pronounced, it would be a schwa, but schwa is often elided in present-day French. When schwa is pronounced vs. elided is a complicated topic.

Comment: The second e in 'appeler' makes an 'er' sound just like in the English word 'waiter'. But it is indeed silent on the end of 'appelle'. I don't see how it can be muet between an l and r though..

Comment: @Hasan: I don't see how pronouncing *appeleras* where the second 'e' is an *e muet* is any harder than pronouncing *ballroom* with only two syllables. (Not that the French always make it an *e muet*.)

Comment: So basically you're saying in modern day French `récupéreras` and `récupéras` are often pronounced in the same way? In any case, it's good that your answer is about `récupéreras`, which is what I asked about, unlike the other answer which is all about `récupèreras` which is not what I asked about.

Comment: @Hasen: récupéreras and récupèreras are nothing more than spelling variants of the same word. Spellings like *récupèreras* are recommended over spellings like *récupéreras* since [1990](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reforms_of_French_orthography#Accents). This is only indirectly related to pronunciation.

Answer (score 2):

In normal speech the vowel "e"  (récupèr**e**ra) is not pronounced. However, this form is still not pronounced as "récupéra", there is a small difference which is enough to distinguish the two; this difference is simply that r is pronounced twice.

**récupèreras** isolated prononciation \ʁe.ky.pɛ.ʁə.ʁa\
                      normal pronunciation  \ʁe.ky.pɛ.ʁ.ʁa\
**récupéra**                                          \ʁe.ky.pe.ʁa\

The following decomposition of the pronunciation gives the key to the pronunciation of the consecutive r's. Pronounce "récupére" and "rat" exactly as they are pronounced normally and finally do the same thing as you manage to pronounce them as close to one another as possible while still not changing the two r's into a long r or blurring them.

Comment: So the pronunciation in the links I gave are all incorrect since they all sound the same? I noticed they also have identical pronunciation on google translate.

Comment: @Hasen There is no doubt these two pronunciations _have_ to sound different; anyone telling you it's not so is not fully aware of how French is pronounced. However, the pronunciations in the first link _are_ different, and they are as should be, although "récupèreras" is pronounced fast. Try and listen again. Nevertheless, you are right in some way, it is sometimes too fast and so the pronunciation is not ideal; in other words it is not pronounced too well.

Comment: @Hasen: I can definitely hear the difference, but that's because English isn't my first language. The main difference is that the \ʁ\ in *récupèreras* is [geminated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gemination), which is not a phonemic feature in English, and therefore can be difficult for native English speakers to recognize as such in other languages.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen is right: the difference between *récupéra* and *récupérera* is gemination. (And let me note that gemination is a very minor feature of English; it's the difference between *black ace* and *black case*.)

Comment: @PeterShorA reference is needed for this last assertion. I know of no geminated r in French. The proper pronunciation of these two r's, which is a difficulty for the language user, is not according to the scheme of the geminated consonants, which is typical of English, but according to the scheme of two distinct consonants.  This is to say that you do not pronounce "serre raquette" as "ces raquettes", where r should be lengthened, but instead as "serre" followed by "raquette".  (1/2)

Comment: @PeterShor  "En français, la gémination n'est généralement pas phonologique et ne permet donc pas de distinguer des mots" (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%A9mination#En_fran%C3%A7ais). However, in a careful pronunciation there is a difference between "récupèrera" et "récupéra", and it is not due to the the "pé/pè" difference.  (2/2)

Comment: @LPH The pronunciations in all the links are all exactly the same....I can confirm that better than most anyone since I have auditory hyperphantasia. I don't even need to listen to them again since I can hear them in the my head any time. But I trust you when you say they are _supposed_ to be different. Those electronic voices in the links I gave are not sophisticated enough to make the difference so they just run the same sound for both.

Comment: @Hasen I did listen to several of them (pérez/pérerez, péront/péreont, péra/pérera, etc.) again. I garantee you there is always a difference, but I agree with you in a very small minority of cases there is not much to catch the ear ; nevertheless, in almost all cases there is a significant difference, which is blurred because of the speaker and the fast speaking rate used, but you should notice that in the case of "rr" there is after the first r the attack of the second r (it's audible); this is the proof that two r's are being pronounced.  (1/2)

Comment: @Hasen You might try and practice the pair "légionnaire aux mains  de grande taille/légionnaire romain de grande taille"  (liaison for the first). In careful speech there has to be a difference. (2/2)

Comment: @LPH I think you've forgotten the question. I'm saying there is no audible difference specifically between *récupéreras* and *récupéras* in any of the links I gave. I even downloaded the audio files and compared them in an audio editor just in case you still didn't agree and they are literally identical. You can play the two sounds simultaneously and they are as one sound. There would be at least some slight distortion or phasing if they were audibly different. Not only is there not a significant difference, there is literally no difference at all.

Comment: @LPH Not sure how to listen to that sentence since it's just text. Like I said, there may be a difference in real life pronunciation but there are none in any of the links I gave.

Comment: @Hasen Reverso pronunciation for *récupéreras* is incorrect. On the other hand, the pronunciation differs between *tu récupéras* and *[tu récupèreras](https://translate.google.com/?sl=auto&tl=en&text=tu%20r%C3%A9cup%C3%A8reras%0A&op=translate)* with Google translate. There is no gemination with it but a "careful" pronunciation where the schwa is not silent. Most French speakers do geminate the R in spontaneous speech, the exception being Southern accent.

Comment: @jlliagre Ok, yes that was my original question, whether those links were incorrect or not. LPH was trying to claim that the pronunciation in the first link for récupéreras and récupéra was different so I was affirming that it is not. You've opened google translate with `tu récupèreras` but the word we're talking about is `tu récupéreras`. Google translate doesn't seem to recognise it and asks 'did you mean?'.

Comment: I hear a slight difference between both Reverso pronunciations, the R sound is clear with '-péras' and 'slightly blurred with '-péreras'.   It doesn't sound natural. Anyway, the traditional spelling "tu récup**é**reras" is misleading. We pronounce this verb "tu récup**è**reras". The 1990 orthographic rectifications allow and advise to use this alternative spelling.

Comment: Google translates pronounces identically both variants (which is the right thing to do).

Comment: @jlliagre As I said already, the two reverso sounds are identical, I opened them in an audio editor. They have the same amplitude, each syllable starts at EXACTLY the same point down to the ms and has the exact same shape...there is zero difference. There's literally less difference between them than a real human pronouncing the SAME word twice...

Comment: @jlliagre If you search for `récupérer conjugaison` in google, all the top websites spell it `récupéreras`. Google translate will also return `tu récupéreras` spelling if you input `you will recover`. As for google translate's pronunciation of `tu récupèreras`  it will attempt to pronounce ANYTHING you input into it with it's French speech...you can even try `rècupèreras`....

Comment: Double check. The reverso sounds are strictly identical until "pé" then differ both visually and audibly. Their [spectrum](https://academo.org/demos/spectrum-analyzer/) is also clearly different. The *récupéreras* version is **20 ms** longer. The fact many websites and Google stick to the traditional spelling is not surprising. The new one is recommended but not mandatory and tbh, I generally use the older one too. The [Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/recuperer) shows both.

Comment: The lenght of the *R* sound is likely what makes the difference to native ears. I did a blind test with someone unaware of what was supposed to be said and the person correctly identified both form.